# how do promises know that the resolve method was called?

Tags: javascript, promise

I know that the state changes to fulfilled and that will automatically call then() but how does a promise know that a resolve() was called not reject() and therefore should change the state to fulfilled ?

It is confusing me because inside the executor we just call resolve("returnValue") we dont explicitly change the state. somehow the promise knows what is happing inside the executor but how?

Example:

```
let promise = new promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   AsynchronousTask(){
   resolve(data)
   }
  AsynchronousTask()
});
```

in the previous example how does the promise object knows that resolve(data) was called and therefore change its internal state if it just executes whatever inside the executor like a regular function?

Comment: Please share some code that you are confused about.

Comment: `resolve` is a function passed to the executor by the Promise constructor ... so, that's how "it knows" I guess - I would recommend looking at the source code of some of the [many compliant promiseAplus implementations](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations) to understand the inner workings of a Promise

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for the refrence, i'll take a look at it, i have no idea why they downvoted me its a genuine question

Comment: your example isn't very useful ... usually the `resolve` is called inside the "asyncrhonous task" - not after it

Comment: personally - I found "pinkyswear" the most readable (I ironed out some bugs in my own implementation thanks to that library) - however I haven't looked through the newer libraries in that list in over 7 years

Comment: @JaromandaX someone gave me a simple answer just in case you are curious, i answered below.

Comment: Thanks. I already know how promises work internally having written my own implementation many years ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions that get passed to the executor are essentially methods of the promise object being created. So when you call resolve(), it's like you're calling the resolve method of the promise - a method that only happens to exist from within the executor and not available from the promise object itself. Think of the promise being defined something like:

```
class SimplePromise {
  state = "pending"
  value = undefined
  error = undefined
  
  resolve = (value) => {
    this.value = value
    this.state = "fulfilled"
  }
  
  reject = (error) => {
    this.error = error
    this.state = "rejected"
  }

  constructor(executor) {
    executor(this.resolve, this.reject)
  }
}

// usage
const myPromise = new SimplePromise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve("test")
})
```